# Blower motor only works in auto when calling for heat

Tags: hvac

My blower motor is only working on auto when calling for heat on the thermostat. But if set to cool blower motor only works when you switch the toggle switch to fan on.

Comment: Is this a new problem or an old one?

Comment: What make and model is your air handler/furnace? Can you post photos of its wiring diagram for that matter?

Comment: Is this a sudden change in behavior that may have come with some possible changes in wiring or the HVAC system, or has it been this way since you moved in, or...? Some details would help a _lot_. Please take the [tour] and read through the [help] on asking questions to learn how to help us help you.